# Splitting a string on spaces but ignore section between double quotes

Tags: string, powershell, split

How is it possible to split this string:

```
$Arguments = '/NOGUI /DATE /EXPAND 4 /SIZEUNIT 3 /SORTTYPE 0 /EXCEL "S:\Test\Brecht\Log Test\Report 13.xlsx" /SHEETNAME "Data set" /SCANPATH "S:\My Folder"'
```

into the following array:

```
/NOGUI
/DATE
/EXPAND
4
/SIZEUNIT
3
/SORTTYPE
0
/EXCEL
"S:\Test\Brecht\Log Test\Report 13.xlsx"
/SHEETNAME
"Data set"
/SCANPATH
"S:\My Folder"
```

When using `$Argument.split(' ')` it also splits the double quoted strings, which is not desired. On the [ScriptingGuy's blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/), they explain what is possible. But I can't seem to find a way to ignore the strings between double quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$Arguments = '/NOGUI /DATE /EXPAND 4 /SIZEUNIT 3 /SORTTYPE 0 /EXCEL "S:\Test\Brecht\Log Test\Report 13.xlsx" /SHEETNAME "Data set" /SCANPATH "S:\My Folder"'

$splitString = [regex]::Split( $Arguments, ' (?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)' )
$splitString
```

Output:

```
/NOGUI
/DATE
/EXPAND
4
/SIZEUNIT
3
/SORTTYPE
0
/EXCEL
"S:\Test\Brecht\Log Test\Report 13.xlsx"
/SHEETNAME
"Data set"
/SCANPATH
"S:\My Folder"
```

Comment: Can you explain that regex string please? Trying to figure it out so I understand it for the future

Comment: Is there also an option to remove double or more whites paces from the array? Otherwise, perfect! Thank you @Ketanbhut

Comment: @ KarkLite1: May be this helps: '\s+(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]+")+$)' .. \s+ will check multiple white spaces. So if there are 2 or more white spaces (example:  3   /SORTTYPE      0  /EXCEL).

Comment: @Ross Lyons: Here is what I could: 

1. [regex]::Split( $anyString, ' (?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)') <-- it splits $anyString by the regex match -- matches the preceding char the ' ' (single space) 
2. (?=pattern) positive look ahead
3. (?:pattern) == (?:[^"]|"[^"]*")* : noncapturing group --> it keeps capturing the match (single space) until it finds first double quote (") and starts omitting capture until it finds another double quote (") -- and continues  - eventually skipping anything between 2 double quotes

Here is .net reference: http://regexhero.net/reference/

Answer (score 3):

Trying to match each element instead, based on [[RESOLVED] Regex Split on Whitespace EXCEPT in single quotes-VBForums](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?820105-RESOLVED-Regex-Split-on-Whitespace-EXCEPT-in-single-quotes).  So anything between double-quotes or non-whitespace.  The -match operator can't do allmatches.

```
$Arguments | select-string '("[^"]*"|\S)+' -AllMatches | % matches | % value

/NOGUI
/DATE
/EXPAND
4
/SIZEUNIT
3
/SORTTYPE
0
/EXCEL
"S:\Test\Brecht\Log Test\Report 13.xlsx"
/SHEETNAME
"Data set"
/SCANPATH
"S:\My Folder"
```

You might need to delete the quotes:

```
$list = $list -replace '"'
```

Comment: I really like this answer. I used `($Arguments | Select-String '("(\\"|[^"])+"|\S)+' -AllMatches).Matches` because I wanted to ignore escaped quotes and insist that there is at least one character between the quotes. Anyways, thank you for this great idea! It's much more flexible than `-Split`.

Comment: @ChrisWong, js2010, thank you!  This works well: `($Str | Select-String '("(\\"|[^"])+"|\S)+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value -replace '"'`